# Return variable from current screen to previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am implementing a 'settings' view in my Flutter app. The idea is all settings will appear in a `ListView`, and when the user will click on a `ListTile`, a `showModalBottomSheet` will pop where the user will be able to manipulate the setting. The only problem I am having is I am unable to migrate the `showModalBottomSheet` to a separate class as I cannot make the new function (outside the class) return the manipulated setting variable. This has lead to a messy code, all in a single class.

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  Page({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Page createState() => _Page();
}

class _Page extends State<Page> {
  var value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text("Age"),
          trailing: Text(value),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              value = _valueSelector(); // This doesn't work, but to give an idea what I want
            });  
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

int _valueSelector(context) { // Doesn't return
  var age = 0;

  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return Wrap(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Slider(
                  value: age.toDouble(),
                  min: 0,
                  max: 18,
                  divisions: 18,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      age = value.toInt();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
    },
  ).whenComplete(() {
    return age; // Not sure if return is supposed to be here
  });
}
```

How can I implement `showModalBottomSheet` in a separate class and just make it return the variable representing the setting chosen by the user?

Comment: Have you read this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data ? Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code,

First, create a class custom_bottom_sheet.dart and add the below code. You can use it everywhere in the project. And also use this library  **modal_bottom_sheet: ^0.2.0+1** to get the **showMaterialModalBottomSheet**.

```
customBottomSheet(BuildContext context, {@required Widget widget}) async {
  return await showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: AppColors.transparent_100,
    barrierColor: AppColors.black_75,
    isDismissible: false,
    enableDrag: true,
    builder: (_, ScrollController scrollController) {
      return widget;
    },
  );
}
```

Sample example code:

Create another class called bottom_sheet_example.dart and add the below code.

```
 class BottomSheetExample {
  static Future getSheet(BuildContext _context,
      {ValueChanged<bool> onChanged}) async {
    await customBottomSheet(
      _context,
      widget: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
        height: 170.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(27.0))),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Were you at Queen Victoria Building?"),
              SizedBox(height: 48),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("No"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(_context).pop();
                        onChanged(false);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 18),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Yes"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(_context).pop();

                        onChanged(true);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Button click to show the bottom sheet

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: yourBodyWidget(),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              /// call BottomSheetExample class
              BottomSheetExample.getSheet(
                context,
                onChanged: (bool result) async {
                  ///
                  /// add your code
                },
              );
            },
            child: Text("show bottom sheet")),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In **onChanged** callback you can return your value(obj/String/num/bool/list).

Thank you!

Comment: Although I had to make many changes to make it compatible with my use case, the idea of Callback works! Thanks!